# How to annotate JSON fields in Django?

Tags: mysql, django

I have a model like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    details = models.JSONField()
    # other fields
```

I want to annotate some fields from this model like this:

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(id__in=given_list).annotate(
         first_name=F('details__first_name'),
         last_name=F('details__last_name')
     )
```

However the `F()` expression is not considering the json keys, its just returning the details field only.

I am using MySQL, so cannot use `KeyTextTransform`.

I tried using RawSQL like this:

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(id__in=given_list).annotate(
         first_name=RawSQL("(details->%s)", ('first_name',)),
         last_name=RawSQL("(details->%s)", ('last_name',))
     )
```

But it was giving this error:

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (3143, 'Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 1.')
```

So what can I do to make everything work as expected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `JSONExtract`, it will be easier to write and understand:

```
from django_mysql.models.functions import JSONExtract
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(id__in=given_list).annotate(
         first_name=JSONExtract('details', '$.first_name'),
         last_name=JSONExtract('details', '$.last_name')
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL [json extractions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-column-path) have a special syntax using `jsonfield->"$.key"`. Try with this:

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(id__in=given_list).annotate(
    first_name=RawSQL("(details->%s)", ('$.first_name',)),
    last_name=RawSQL("(details->%s)", ('$.last_name',))
)
```

Comment: MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'first_name'')) AS `first_name`, ((proxy_details->'$.'last_name'')) AS `las' at line 1")

Comment: Try now, I forgot that django quotes the params

Answer (score -2):

You can just add properties to your `MyModel` and have them return the corresponding information

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    details = models.JSONField()
    
    @property
    def first_name(self):
        return self.details['first_name']
    @property    
    def last_name(self):
        return self.details['last_name']
```