# Annotate dict data from related field Django

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-annotate

I have a model `MyModel` that contains a JSONField named `calculo` in MySQL and I want to annotate the value of `premio` to perform aggregated sum. How can I make this work?

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    calculo = JSONField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

I have tried this but got an empty dict.

```
 qs = MyModel.annotate(value=F('calculo__premio'))
```

Fairfax field:

```
'{"sc_ha": 2.77, "premio": 27735.84, "status": "1"}'
```

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63048183/2785080

Comment: It help a lot @Ben! Thanks!